# Get id from url using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get id from my index.php using PDO. Under my index.php code i have pass the id through a url to my topic.php file. Now I dont know how to get the id using PDO.

This is my code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT
            topicid,
            topicsubject
        FROM
            topics
        WHERE
            topicid = ? ";

$result = $db->prepare($sql);

$result->bindValue(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);


$result->execute();


$numrows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Well i am not sure whether my code is right or wrong. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: `$id = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['topicid']; // 5.4 or greater`

Comment: Edit your previous question if you want to concretize the topic.

Comment: @mariomy previous question was about fetching the row using pdo but this question is about getting id from url using pdo....